# How to solve Javascript fetch API showing 415 error?

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript fetch() method to hit an api. I am getting the response well in postman but getting error while running the html file.Can anyone solve?

```
index.html
-----------------
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      profiles: [
        {email: 'xxx@klaviyo.com'},
        {phone_number: '+1234567896'}
      ]
    })
  };


fetch("https://a.klaviyo.com/api/list/yyyyyyyyyyy/members?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: The [`415 HTTP Response Code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) means that the server refuses the content type of your request. Maybe the API you're calling doesn't expect `JSON` for that endpoint.

Comment: So what shall I do? Shall I change anything in code?

Comment: @ths the API does seem to expect JSON https://developers.klaviyo.com/en/reference/add-members

Comment: Have you tried using `'Content-Type'` instead of `'content-type'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did not see the OP's API docs (and I won't). I only suggested a possible cause based on the error code the OP mentioned (which is `415`).

Comment: Yes tried with 'Content-Type' but still showing error as 415